Vite App Build doesn't work with changing K8s Configmap
I recently deployed a new Vite image from my dev envrionment to my prod envrionment and noticed that the client didn't work because it was still using the envrionment variables from dev, even when changing the configmap.
From there I realized that Vite (and generally other client bundlers) build statically, meaning the envs are replaced on build which means I can't inject them dynamically with a configmap.
That's a problem because I have multiple envrionments I need my Image to support and I can't go and "break" the Image for one envrionment to make it work on another.
I tried doing a trick using window.env which a team member of mine used on our old webpack images but I couldn't get it to work.
Is there a way to configure Vite to build dynamically? Or maybe there is a trick using window.evn for Vite and I just didn't manage to implement it correctly.
Thanks
